# impossible build android app bundle :app:bundleReleaseResources FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, build.gradle

I'm trying to build my android application but it doesn't work. I use eas to build my app bundle. When I run gradlew I get this error and my build failed:

> Task :app:bundleReleaseResources FAILED

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

    import com.android.build.OutputFile
    project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: (findProperty('expo.jsEngine') ?: "jsc") == "hermes",
    cliPath: "../../node_modules/react-native/cli.js",
    hermesCommand: "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/%OS-BIN%/hermesc",
    composeSourceMapsPath: "node_mdoules/react-native/scripts/compose-source-maps.js",

]
apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../react.gradle")
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.yieldinvest.yield'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.3"
        missingDimensionStrategy ('store', 'play')

        multiDexEnabled true //important
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd check the logcat in Android Studio for specific error(s). Also, what does your log say in whatever IDE you're using?

Comment: If there is any more information in your log output it would be very useful.  It's hard to understand the problem from just that line.

Comment: @whaleberg Yes sure, the logs file is here. I couldn't put it all in stackoverflow so I put it in a notepad below. [Logs](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fc26f30ae78b559ecc8347357be53c2920220331082326/0ee94b)

Comment: @AleksandarZoric I don't use Android Studio I test with yarn start by plugging my device directly and I compile using eas build -p android